# How to understand the Wheeler-de Witt equation correctly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology

I am a student and for me it is still quite difficult to understand the Wheeler-de Witt equation for the wave function of the Universe. This is a kind of analogue of the Schrödinger equation, which describes the entire Universe in a quantum way. And this equation does not depend on time, that is, from this point of view, the Universe does not evolve in time. On the other hand, our observations show the opposite, that the universe changes over time.

This is due to the fact that for observations it is necessary to divide the Universe into two parts: i) the observer with his measuring instrument, in particular, the clock, ii) the rest of the Universe. And from this point of view, the state of the rest of the universe depends on the state of the observer's clock, different states of the clock correspond to different states of the rest of the universe. In other words, for the observer, the rest of the universe evolves over time.

I have the following question. Consider two absolutely identical wave functions of two universes. After the big bang, decoherence makes each of them effectively semiclassical, and from that point on, the classical history of each of these universes proceeds differently (depending on the initial conditions). And an observer in one universe will see a slightly different evolution of his universe than an observer in another universe? Do I understand correctly?